# Check if a string is in a list of letters - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list which contains letters, and I need to check if a pre-determined word located in another list is horizontally inside this list of letters.

i.e.:

```
mat_input = [['v', 'e', 'd', 'j', 'n', 'a', 'e', 'o'], ['i', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'u'], ['s', 'u', 'e', 'w', 'e', 't', 'a', 'e']]


words_to_search = ['python', 'fox']
```

I don't need to tell if a word was not found, but if it was I need to tell which one.

My problem is that so far I've tried to compare letter by letter, in a loop similar to this:

```
for i in range(n):                         # n = number of words
  for j in range(len(word_to_search[i])):  # size of the word I'm searching
    for k in range(h):                     # h = height of crossword
      for m in range(l):                   # l = lenght of crossword
```

But it's not working, inside the last loop I tried several if/else conditions to tell if the whole word was found. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.join`:

```
mat_input = [['v', 'e', 'd', 'j', 'n', 'a', 'e', 'o'], ['i', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'u'], ['s', 'u', 'e', 'w', 'e', 't', 'a', 'e']]
words_to_search = ['python', 'fox']
joined_input = list(map(''.join, mat_input))
results = {i:any(i in b or i in b[::-1] for b in joined_input) for i in words_to_search}
```

Output:

```
{'python': True, 'fox': False}
```

Comment: Although you may want to prepare the strings ahead of time if you need to use them a lot.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Good point. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: The user also wants to know which index of mat_input contained the string, so instead of any you could use a "where" type command.

Comment: This returns `False, False` for me

Comment: @Ajax1234 very nice solution =)

Comment: What if I have a reversed word in my puzzle. Instead of 'python' I had 'nohtyp' and I needed to check if 'python' was still in that puzzle?

Comment: @IgorBraga You can check if the word exists in the reversed substring. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by joining each sublist in `mat_input` into one string:

```
mat_input_joined = [''.join(x) for x in mat_input]
```

Then loop over your words to search and simply use the `in` operator to see if the word is contained in each string:

```
for word_to_search in words_to_search:
    result = [word_to_search in x for x in mat_input_joined]
    print('Word:',word_to_search,'found in indices:',[i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x])
```

Result:

```
Word: python found in indices: [1]
Word: fox found in indices: []
```